# place div on top of div not working on third div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following 3 divs. filler is on top of logo. All 3 div's line up correctly when logo has margin-left:100px.  But when I change margin-left: to margin-left:200px the background gets pushed to the next line.  Why does filler overlap logo but I'm unable to get filler and logo to overlap bg?

```js
var logo = document.querySelector("#logo");
var bg = document.querySelector("#bg");

var rect_logo = logo.getBoundingClientRect();
var rect_bg = bg.getBoundingClientRect();

var filler = document.getElementById('filler');

filler.style.height = logo.offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100vw;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#filler {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 15;
  margin-left: -75px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#bg {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 90vw;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-left: -75px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='logo'>LOGO</div>
  <div id='filler'></div>
  <div id='bg'>BackGround</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to resolve this is to add  **position:absolute** to your background. It will work fine.The default position value is static for your background thats why it was pushing to the next line.

```js
var logo = document.querySelector( "#logo" );
  var bg = document.querySelector( "#bg" );



  var rect_logo = logo.getBoundingClientRect();
  var rect_bg =   bg.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  
  
  
  
  var filler = document.getElementById('filler');
  filler.style.height=logo.offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
#container{

height:100vw;}

#logo{
display:inline-block;
color:white;
background-color:lightblue;
position:relative;
width:20%;
height:5%;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
z-index:10;
margin-left:300px;
overflow:visible;


}

#filler{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
width:50px;
background-color:green;
vertical-align:top;
z-index:15;
margin-left:-75px;
overflow:visible;


}
#bg{
display:inline-block;
color:white;
background-color:blue;
width:50%;
float:right;
height:90vw;
overflow:visible;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
margin-left:-75px;
position:absolute;

}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
   <div id='logo'>LOGO</div>
   <div id='filler'></div>
   <div id='bg'>BackGround</div>
</div>
```

better approach would be to put the other two divs inside the background div

Answer (score 0):

The total width of your elements is `50% + 20% + 50px` then you have two negative margin (`-150px`) which will give us a total of `70% - 100px` which means that you can still use `30% + 100px` inside your margin before your create a line break. a litte lower than this because we need to also consider the white spaces.

Here is to illustrate:

```js
var logo = document.querySelector("#logo");
var bg = document.querySelector("#bg");



var rect_logo = logo.getBoundingClientRect();
var rect_bg = bg.getBoundingClientRect();





var filler = document.getElementById('filler');
filler.style.height = logo.offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100vw;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: calc(30% + 95px);
  overflow: visible;
}

#filler {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 15;
  margin-left: -75px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#bg {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 90vw;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-left: -75px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='logo'>LOGO</div>
  <div id='filler'></div>
  <div id='bg'>BackGround</div>
</div>
```

Make the value a little bigger and the blue is on a new line

```js
var logo = document.querySelector("#logo");
var bg = document.querySelector("#bg");



var rect_logo = logo.getBoundingClientRect();
var rect_bg = bg.getBoundingClientRect();





var filler = document.getElementById('filler');
filler.style.height = logo.offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100vw;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: calc(30% + 98px);
  overflow: visible;
}

#filler {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 15;
  margin-left: -75px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#bg {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 90vw;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-left: -75px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='logo'>LOGO</div>
  <div id='filler'></div>
  <div id='bg'>BackGround</div>
</div>
```

So simply make sure that you don't exceed `100%` considering all the margin and the width.